# Confirmar antes de enviar formulário com input submit

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando fazer um botão que só envie o formulário quando eu clico em <kbd>OK</kbd>, mas esse meu, mesmo eu clicando em <kbd>Cancelar</kbd>, tá sendo enviado.

JavaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
function pergunta(){ 
   if (confirm('Tem certeza que quer enviar este pedido?')){ 
      document.enviarform.submit() 
   } 
} 
</script>
```

Botão:

```
<form name='apagar' id='apagar' action='formulario.php' method='post'>
<input type=submit value=enviar name=enviarform onclick='pergunta();'>
```

Onde está o erro?

Obs: quando coloco `type=button` no lugar de `type=submit` não faz nenhuma ação (nem envia, nem nada).

Obs2: quando no lugar de `<input>` coloco um `<button>`, envia da mesma forma (sem dar o OK).

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Coloquei... continua enviando mesmo quando clico no cancelar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altere o `onclick` colocando `return` antes da função. Com isso você irá esperar uma resposta `true` ou `false` da função. Se retornar `true` irá enviar o form, se retornar `false`, o submit é cancelado:

```js
function pergunta(){ 
   // retorna true se confirmado, ou false se cancelado
   return confirm('Tem certeza que quer enviar este pedido?');
}
```

```html
<form name='apagar' id='apagar' action='formulario.php' method='post'>
   <input type=submit value=enviar name=enviarform onclick='return pergunta();'>
</form>
```

> Não precisa de `document.enviarform.submit()` porque a ação do botão
>   já é de submit.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado!!!

Comment: De nada jovem! Veja como agradecer aqui -> [tour] ;)